# Change legend label based on dataframe value

Tags: matplotlib

I currently have an X value `df["long"]` and a Y value `df["lat"]`. Each X and Y point represents a house and I'm wanting the scatter points to appear blue if `df["waterfront"]` = 0 or red if `df["waterfront"]` = 1.

My attempt is shown below but I just can't figure out how to insert both labels and legends.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'long': [1, 2], 'lat': [3, 4], 'waterfront': [0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

colors = {0:'tab:blue', 1:'tab:red'}

plt.scatter(df['long'], df['lat'], 
            c=[colors[i] for i in df['waterfront']], 
            zorder=3, label=("Without Waterfront","With Waterfront"))
plt.xlabel ("Longitude")
plt.ylabel ("Latitude")
plt.title ("Longitude versus Latitude")
plt.grid(zorder=0)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Actual Output
[image: Actual Output]

Expected Output
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: There's a `label` keyword argument to `plt.scatter()` which you can feed the house name or whatever identifier then that will be automatically shown via the legend.

Comment: @mechanical_meat I'm only able to figure out how to insert 1 label, for the blue points. I can't figure out how to insert 2 labels depending on the colour of the point.

Comment: Please show that attempt then, and what's going wrong with it.

Comment: @mechanical_meat I've added it

Comment: @mechanical_meat how come you deleted your answer?

Comment: I have to figure out why it works only for part of it. Give me a moment please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use seaborn in order to do this simply:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# data 
d = {'long': [1, 2], 'lat': [3, 4], 'waterfront': [0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# plot colors
colors = {0:'tab:blue', 1:'tab:red'}

# create scatter plot
g = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="long", y="lat", hue="waterfront", palette=colors)

# set legend outside plot
g.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), ncol=1)

# change legend labels
for t, l in zip(g.legend_.texts, ["Without Waterfront", "With Waterfront"]):
    t.set_text(l)

# set labels and plot
plt.xlabel ("Longitude")
plt.ylabel ("Latitude")
plt.title ("Longitude versus Latitude")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output1]

Solution without seaborn:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data 
d = {'long': [1, 2], 'lat': [3, 4], 'waterfront': [0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# create scatter plot
plt.scatter(df.loc[df['waterfront'] == 0,'long'], df.loc[df['waterfront'] == 0,'lat'], 
            color='tab:blue', label="Without Waterfront")
plt.scatter(df.loc[df['waterfront'] == 1,'long'], df.loc[df['waterfront'] == 1,'lat'], 
            color='tab:red', label="With Waterfront")

# set labels and plot
plt.xlabel ("Longitude")
plt.ylabel ("Latitude")
plt.title ("Longitude versus Latitude")
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), ncol=1)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output2]

Comment: Is there a way to do it without importing another library like seaborn?

Comment: @Ceiun I added a solution without seaborn :)